# React Native useEffect() triggers screen navigation twice

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo

Been working on an application (written in React Native - using **expo**) that uses multiple screens and a fixed Footer that allows navigation between pages. The Footer has three icons, one for each page.

Everything worked well, the problem starting to appear when we tried to highlight the icon of the selected page.

This is how our `Footer.js` looks like:

```
const Footer = (props: Props) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [activeIcon, setActiveIcon] = useState('MessageFeed');

    useEffect(() => {
        // Navigate to the activeIcon route after state update
        navigation.navigate(activeIcon);
    }, [activeIcon, navigation]);

    const handleIconClick = (routeName) => {
        setActiveIcon(routeName); // Update active icon immediately
    };

    return (
        <View style={{flex: 0.1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', marginTop: 10}}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.bottomBtn} onPress={() => handleIconClick('MyProfile')}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} size={30} color={activeIcon === 'MyProfile' ? '#fb5b5a' : null}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.bottomBtn} onPress={() => handleIconClick('MessageFeed')}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHouse} size={30} color={activeIcon === 'MessageFeed' ? '#fb5b5a' : null}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.bottomBtn} onPress={() => handleIconClick('CreateTextMessage')}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCirclePlus} size={30} color={activeIcon === 'CreateTextMessage' ? '#fb5b5a' : null}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
```

As you can see, whenever one of the three buttons are pressed, the `handleIconClick()` is triggered, which sets the `activeIcon` state on the icon pressed. By changing the state of the icon, the `useEffect()` hook should be triggered, which also triggers navigation on the selected page, while displaying the proper highlighted icon.

In my case, this doesn't happen. The icon changes properly, but the screen doesn't seem to change at all. I tried to `console.log(activeIcon)` inside the `useEffect()` logic, and it seems that every time I press on an icon, the `useEffect()` outputs two messages: the selected route, and then it goes back to `MessageFeed`. It seems that it is somehow triggered twice. Once properly, but then it navigates back to the initial page.

The `console.log()` output looks like this, when I click the first button while the middle one is selected:

```
LOG  MyProfile
LOG  MessageFeed
```

What may be the problem in this case? Why is `useEffect()` triggered twice? Or am I missing something?

Comment: My guess is that when you call navigate, your component is re-rendered, which would set activeIcon back to its default value. You would get the first log from the component before the re-render and the second when it is re-rendered. I may be wrong, because I don't know how you app is structured

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
const handleIconClick = (routeName) => {
    setActiveIcon(routeName)
    navigation.navigate(routeName)
}
```

Comment: So no `useEffect`?

Comment: just try it.....